# For Example, I Have eg.com, How Can I Allow Users to Register a Subdomain Under It?

Tags: dns, open-source, subdomain, registration, forwarding

Let say I own the *eg.com* domain. How can I develop a registration service that will allow my users to register a domain such *example.eg.com* on my website, with features such **Domain Forwarding**, **DNS Service** and **Custom DNS**?

1. Is there an open source software that can able to manage that?
2. Can I make it with just a basic web hosting plan and what are the hosting features' requirements?

I hope I'll get a nice answer! Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

A Managed DNS service with API access can allow you to write a script to automate this process. Once it is forwarded to a server, the server can decide where to direct traffic based on the requested FQDN.

Comment: Nice.. But there's no good Managed DNS service with API without a cost. I think I can use CloudFlare API to develop a free domain registration service. If you knew a free DNS service that's better than CloudFlare for my purpose, please drop it here. Thanks!